# Center h1 in container's "before" pseudo element

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I am working on a project in which I have some h1 text and an animation of a green rectangle comes in from the right side and highlights the text. The green rectangle is created using the container's "before" pseudo element. The problem I'm trying to solve is how to vertically center the text in the green rectangle. You can see what I tried below.

```css
.h1-text-container {
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
}

.h1-text-container h1 {
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.h1-text-container::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: #8ac54d;
  animation-name: greenrectangleinout;
  animation-duration: 2000ms;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
  animation-play-state: runnning;
  height: 100px;
}

@keyframes greenrectangleinout {
  from {
    transform: scaleX(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: scaleX(100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="h1-text-container">
  <h1>H1 TEXT</h1>
</div>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/ericsayag/pen/vYjREyQ

Answer (score 4):

Add `position: relative` to the container div. Your absolute positioning of the pseudo element is relative to the body, but by adding the relative positioning to the div, it becomes relative to the div instead.

```css
.h1-text-container {
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.h1-text-container h1 {
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.h1-text-container::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: #8ac54d;
  animation-name: greenrectangleinout;
  animation-duration: 2000ms;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
  animation-play-state: runnning;
  height: 100px;
}

@keyframes greenrectangleinout {
  from {
    transform: scaleX(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: scaleX(100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="h1-text-container">
  <h1>H1 TEXT</h1>
</div>
```